# Disable submit button if all three of three specific dropdown fields are empty

Tags: jquery, attr, conditional-statements, submit-button, javascript

There are four dropdowns in the form. One is optional. Of the other three, at least one has to be chosen. I have a script that I'm using on a form with one field, that disables submit until a selection is made. But I can't figure out and can't find how to adapt it to be disabled until at least one of three specific dropdowns has a selection made. Here's the current script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#ssbbcmodal-attribute').change(function() {
        var empty = false;
        $('#ssbbcmodal-attribute').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == null) {
                empty = true;
            }
        });
        if (empty) {
            $('#ssbbcmodal-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#ssbbcmodal-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})()
```

**UPDATE 1**

I might have thought of a way to do it. Will be back soon with update.

**UPDATE 2**

OK, my way to do it didn't work, probably because I'm guessing at this. Here's what I tried:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var empty = false;

    $('#sseomodal-level').change(function() {
        var levelempty = false;
        $('#sseomodal-level').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == null) {
                levelempty = true;
            }
        });
    });
    $('#sseomodal-username').change(function() {
        var userempty = false;
        $('#sseomodal-username').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == null) {
                userempty = true;
            }
        });
    });
    $('#sseomodal-logged').change(function() {
        var loggedempty = false;
        $('#sseomodal-logged').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == null) {
                loggedempty = true;
            }
        });
    });     

if (levelempty === true && userempty === true && loggedempty === true)
    {empty = false}
 if (empty) {
            $('#sseomodal-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#sseomodal-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
})()
```

The disabled attribute is never removed with this, i.e., it doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't this line: `{empty = false}` be `{empty = true}` ? If level/user/logged are all empty, then you want `empty` to be *true*, yes?

Comment: But... still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Try simplifying everything -- just detect if one of those select controls was changed and then remove the disabled attribute. Once you have that working, then replace the original code bit by bit till you find the error.

Comment: Sure thing. Will do. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: See my updated answer with detailed code example re above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3HeCj/1/)**

The three selects you must test can each have a class (something like `require_one`).

When any select box is changed, check if it has that class. If so, then remove the disabled attribute from the Select button.

Example code:

```
$('#mySubmit').attr('disabled','disabled');

$('select').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('require_one') ){
        $('#mySubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

---

For your own code, try reducing it to just this and see if it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sseomodal-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $('[id^=sseomodal]').change(function() {
        var myId = $(this).attr('id');
        if (myId == 'sseomodal-level' || myId == 'sseomodal-username' || myId == 'sseomodal-logged') {
            $('#sseomodal-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });

}); // END document.ready
```

Comment: Thanks, gibberish. This works in the fiddle, but it doesn't work in my TinyMCE modal. I copied what I had straight from my modal into a fiddle, and it worked there, brought it back to the modal, doesn't work. I had that same problem last night when I was working on the code in the original post. Lots of them worked in the fiddles but not in my modal. Until I came across the one I posted, which works. I failed to mention that two of the selects are multiple (multiselect), but that shouldn't affect it, should it? I mean, it does work in the fiddle, so probably not.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work either. It just remains disabled. I also tried using the original code from my original post, and while it works on another form of mine, it doesn't work on this one. The only difference I can think of is that this particular form has two multiselects whose values are populated dynamically by PHP, but I'm not sure why that would prevent this from working. Stumped.

Comment: @Thom Simplify/Reduce. Solve. Replace.

Comment: Also try some tests that let you know if you are correctly selecting / reading the elements in question. Example: Add a new button which, when clicked: `$('#sseomodal-submit').removeAttr('disabled');`