# Disable Submit button if none of selector options is selected

Tags: javascript, select, submit

I would like to disable the Submit button on a search form that only contains select dropdowns. There are several similar questions here but I most of them deal with  fields. The closest thing to my case is [Disable submit button if all three of three specific dropdown fields are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253708/disable-submit-button-if-all-three-of-three-specific-dropdown-fields-are-empty). I modified the solution supplied in JSFiddle to feature an empty option, and did get it working -- but only in JSFiddle, not on my page.

I use the same code from the proposed answer (only changed IDs):

```
$('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');

$('select').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('require_one') ){
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});

$('#submit').click(function() {
   $('#searchform').submit(); 
});
```

I add the above code right after I include the jquery.js (v. 1.9.1).
I generate the form dynamically, but in JSFiddle I use exactly what is seen in the page source: http://jsfiddle.net/cheeseus/d5xz6aw8/8/

I have no idea why I can't get it to work on the actual page, hope those more knowledgeable can help sort it out.

And, if possible, I would also like the Submit button to be disabled again if all three selects are set to blank values again.

Comment: Because you generate the form dynamically, you need to use jQuery's `on()` function. e.g. `$('select').on('change', function() {...});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually don't like using the ID(3) for CSS selector since you can have only one ID selector with that name on the document and there might be another element already with the same ID. How about using the class hierarchy instead to pinpoint the button element?
In any case you need to re-check the count everytime what you select on what is empty:

```
var $submitButton=$('.selector .btn');
var $selectors=$('.selector select.require_one');
$submitButton.attr('disabled','disabled');

$('.selector select.require_one').change(function(){
  var $empty=$selectors.filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });
    if ( $selectors.filter(function() { return this.value == ""; }).length == $selectors.length ){
             $submitButton.attr('disabled','disabled');        
    } else
    {
        $submitButton.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});



$submitButton.click(function() {
   $('#searchform').submit(); 
});
```

[JSFiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/gkohen/t7j08wbn/22/)

Comment: Would it be possible to recreate it or send the page to a location it can be recreated?

Comment: It just dawned on me to insert the Javascript snippet AFTER the search form -- and it worked! :)

The only problem is that after the form is submitted, I set the select option(s) which was/were selected to "selected="selected"", but the SEARCH button is disabled on load.

Comment: This might not be the cleanest way but you could move the logic inside the change event handler to a function and then call that function both on change and instead of setting the submit button initially to disabled.

Comment: I am afraid my Javascript knowledge is not sufficient to understand what you are proposing, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple count to see if you should display the button or not. Here is jQuery  code.

```
var count = 0;
$('.require_one').change(function() {
    count++;
    if (count >= 3) {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});

$('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you didn't check is your document ready.
I added few improvements:

- caching jquery object in variables, makes your code a bit faster (you don't look for it everytime select is beeing changes).
- used recommended way of binding events - 'on' function
- 'disabled' is property not an attribute, jQuery has dedicated method to use
- on select change - check all selects if there is any not selected, it there is - set prop disabled to true, otherwise set false.
- instead of disabling submit at initialization, trigger same action you do when selected is beeing changed (if you start with option selected in all select initial state won't be disabled).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $submit  = $('#submit');
    var $selects = $('select.require_one');

    $submit.on("click", function() {
        $('#searchform').submit(); 
    });

    $selects
        .on("change", function(){
            var $not_selected = $selects.filter(function() {
                return !$(this).val();
            });
            $submit.prop('disabled', $not_selected.length ? true : false);
        })
        .first()
        .triggerHandler('change');    
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This script only enables the Submit button when ALL three selects are selected, whereas I want it to enable if any of the three is selected.